# Find and replace text in first column of tables

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I have a document with multiple tables and I need to look **only** in every cell of first column and do the next replacement:

- *find:* ([0-9]{1;2}).^s
- *replace:* \1.^p

Is it possible to choose in which column to look, in order to use it for other documents, replacements?

Comment: Can you please share the part of code where you are facing the problem.

Comment: It is not a part of some code, it is just one find/replace with wildcards, and I had to go step by step (cell by cell), in column 1, in order to break the number from the text. 
Example: 
I have: 
1. some text
2. some text
And I need to make it look like this:
1.(^p)
the text....
2.(^p)
the text...

I hope this is more clear.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
Sub Replace_in_Tables(strFind As String, strReplace As String, intColumn As Integer)

    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oRow As Row

    For Each oTable In ThisDocument.Tables

        For Each oRow In oTable.Rows
            oTable.Cell(oRow.Index, intColumn).Range.Text = Replace(oTable.Cell(oRow.Index, intColumn).Range.Text, strFind, strReplace)
        Next oRow

    Next oTable

End Sub
```

Call it like this :

```
Sub test()

    ' replace in all tables of this document, on column 1, the string "aaa" with "xxxxxxxxxxx"

    Replace_in_Tables "aaa", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", 1

End Sub
```

This will replace strings only... Not sure if your find/replace example was a regexp or not, as it is not clearly stated in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Yes... in my find/replace I used wildcards.

Comment: Thank you for this code. The problem is that I don't know how to make it work. I guess I have to complete some values somewhere, because isn't working in this form. I am newer in VBA coding... can you be more explicit how to implement this code (where should I put the number of column in which this code should look, where I have to put the find regexp and where to put the replace regexp). And what should I do with the seconde code? Thank you very much.